# Run ElastAlert only during certain times

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

We are using ElastAlert for alerting on Elasticsearch data, and we have a bunch of rules. Now, some of those rules only make sense to run within business hours (like weekdays) and we would like to define the periods when the rule should run as part of the rule itself.

Would like to know if ElastAlert itself has this feature, or is there something that we can do it to implement this feature on our side.

Comment: There are some ideas here: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/588#issuecomment-282256938

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta feature for this already, which supports cron syntax to define when the rule should run: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/492#issuecomment-438024625

Another workaround is using [Enhancements](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/adding_enhancements.html), a way of injecting custom code in ElastAlert, which run for every match. In the enhancement, you could essentially check if the time corresponds to non-business hours and drop the match in case.